# Does the voltage supplied to a CPU differ per core?

Tags: voltage, cpu, overclocking

I'm currently trying to find a range of safe voltages for CPU overclocking.

As a start, I looked at the automatic stock voltages: Without any Turbo-functions, the voltages in this case range from 0.86 - 1.34 V ("V Core") under load. However, when the Turbo-clock is active, the upper limit will increase to 1.4 V, with active Load-Line Calibration rarely up to 1.42 V under load.

Since Turbo-clocks are only active on up to two cores at a time when the load is distributable, I was wondering if the whole CPU will run on 1.4+ V when the Turbo is active or just those two specific cores and the rest of the cores keep running on 1.34 V maximum depending on their load?

Comment: First of all you need to tell us what CPU you are talking about. There will be no help, if we don't no what you are talking about. Additionally this is not really the correct SE for this question. This is about electronics development.

Comment: Does the motherboard have one VRM or two?

Comment: Modern CPU have a lot of power gates that can turn off voltage for unused parts of a core.

Comment: Hello jusaca, the specific CPU in question would be an AMD FX-8350 processor, so not a very old, but I supposed that such functionality wouldn't just be available on specific models and wanted to ask in general. I'm sorry if this is the wrong community, but I've asked overclocking questions here before and I figured that since this was more related to the electronic functioning of the CPU, it was relevant. (I'm not looking for overlocking tips for my CPU, I just was curious about the power delivery to the cores.)

Comment: Hi peufeu, I suspect one VRM. To be sure, it is a regular single-CPU consumer board, an ASUS M4A89TD (https://www.asus.com/Motherboards/M4A89TD_PROUSB3/)

Comment: GPU , RAM , CPU will have their own VRM's , but all cores share the same while core clocks are independant.  Have your tried/fried? TurboV EVO interface with Turbo Unlocker  looks pretty safe. Nice passive heatsink

Comment: Hello Tony, no - so far, everything has been fine. I've had this hardware for years running on stock values and wanted to get more preformance out of it, so I replaced all thermal compounds/pads on the board and the CPU and ran some overclocking tests. The system seems stable at 4.5 GHz with automatic stock voltages and no Turbo, but when the Turbo is turned on, the automatic voltages are raised dramatically (as explained in the question). That's when I was wondering if just the Turbo cores or all cores are fed that additional power, because practically seen, that would raise the upper limit.